# Reverse string code error

Tags: java, string, reverse

The program supposed to ask the user to enter a string then the program will reverse it and display it, but the code only return the first letter

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
    String s = scan.next();

        int x = s.length();

        char c = ' ';
        for(int i=x-1; i>=0;i--){
                c = s.charAt(i);
        }

            System.out.print("The reverse of String " + s + " is ");
            System.out.print(c);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
    Enter a String: Welcome
    The reverse of String Welcome is W
```

Comment: You don't ever create a new string (just a single character assignation from last character to first character)

Comment: How exactly you're going to store a string within a char?

Comment: why r u using char it can hold only one char

Comment: I wasn't going to use char but the teacher used it in an example different from this and then asked to solve this I was wondering how would it work.
Thanks for the help all :D !

Answer (score 1):

Change  `char c = ' ';` to `String reverse="";` and append the character to it for each iteration.

The problem in your code is `char c` can hold only one character at a time.

Do like this

```
 String reverse ="";
 for(int i=s.length()-1; i>=0;i--){
      reverse += s.charAt(i);
 }

 System.out.print(reverse);
```

Comment: **Please don't teach string concatenation like this**. They might continue to use it. Use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting value of `c` in each iteration, change it to string and add to it in the loop

```
String c = "";
for(int i=x-1; i>=0;i--){
  c += s.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: **Please don't teach string concatenation like this**. They might continue to use it. Use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

A character is one letter; not a string.... the easiest way to do this, would be to use a StringBuilder like so -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
    String s = scan.next();

    // int x = s.length();
    // char c = ' ';
    // for (int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //  c = s.charAt(i);
    //}
    StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder(s);
    c = c.reverse();
    System.out.print("The reverse of String " + s + " is ");
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Or, if you want to use your current approach you can (by printing one character at time) like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
    String s = scan.next();

    System.out.print("The reverse of String " + s + " is ");
    int x = s.length();
    for (int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make laugh your teacher (or maybe not) ;)

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.reverse(s)
```

or without lib:

```
new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficient approach:

```
char[] strArray = s.toCharArray();

int len = strArray.length;
int max = (int)Math.ceil(len / 2.0);

char t;
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
  t = strArray[i];
  strArray[i] = strArray[len - i - 1];
  strArray[len - i - 1] = t;
}

System.out.println(String.valueOf(strArray));
```